# Como garantir que todas as threads executaram?

Tags: java, paralelismo

Como posso garantir que o método get de um FutureTask só será chamado quando todas as threads já tiverem executado?

Eu tenho este método :

```
for (int j = 0; j < threadNum; j++) {
        FutureTask<Integer> futureTask = taskList.get(j);
        if(!taskList.get(j).isDone()){
            System.out.println("Não terminou: ");
        }
        amount += futureTask.get();

    }
```

Eu deveria fazer um loop infinito antes deste for para garantir que só chegará aqui quando todas as threads terminarem sua execução ou há uma outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: O método `futureTask.get()` espera a thread terminar para obter seu valor. É tipo um "esperar e então obter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando **FutureTask** você não precisa de loop para verificar se já terminou. Também não precisa de um método específico para aguardar terminar. O próprio método **get** faz as duas coisas - espera terminar e então obtém o valor computado.

Seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
for (FutureTask<Integer> futureTask : taskList) {
    amount += futureTask.get();
}
```